# Appropriate data structure for storing the data

Tags: java, hashset

I should store the following data, where the first integer is unique:

```
<118,15>
<429,15>
<625,30>
```

Is `HashSet<Integer,Integer>` the good option to store this?

Comment: As long as the keys are unique, sure. Or a `HashMap`.

Comment: 1. Can you guarantee key uniqueness? 2. What should happen if an already existing key is used in an insert/put/add? 3. In what way do you want to interact with that data structure? -> Search for exact keys, values? Search for margins -> key <100 >50? 4. Do you want to delete pairs from the data structure?

Comment: You should use HashMap.. which contain key value pair

Comment: You're giving us too little information to be able to tell whether a `HashSet` would be a good option. What are you going to use this data for?

Comment: @Klausos Please provide more details how you want to implement it. And what are all the restrictions.As per your rules there are well defined structures you can pick the most suitable. As for HashSet and HashMap:: `In HashMap you can store <key,value> pair,And as you are storing Integer the performance would be really good.` 
`Where as HashSet can only store <key>.Performance does not matter here because it can not solve your purpose of saving <key,value>pair.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set` is for uniqueness, although there is nothing for `key -> value` thing in `Set` collections. So,

```
HashSet<Integer,Integer>
```

**does not exists at all.**

Probably `Map` is what you're looking for, as soon as you have a unique Integer to use as key.

Example:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(118, 15); //the key is 118, value is 15
map.put(429, 15);
map.put(625, 30);
map.get(118);     //get the value for the key 118, so it returns 15
```

It you can't guarantee the uniqueness of any of `Integer`s, you probably can use:

```
List<Integer[]> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(new Integer[] {185, 15});
ints.add(new Integer[] {429, 15});
ints.add(new Integer[] {625, 15});
```

**EDIT**

As you explained through review, the first element is unique, so you're probably ok with the `Map` interface, as it is the main purpose of it.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` is applicable when there's structure like `key -> value`, where `key`s are unique.

If you want just to store pairs of integers, you have to create your own data type, something like:

```
public class MyTuple /* here should be adequate name */ {
    int first, second; // there too
    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    public MyTuple(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

If you're a bit lazy, you can use `Map.Entry` for this purpose, but it's not correct in Java world, you should have one class for one purpose and it should refrect it's designation.

Some libraries have their own implementation of `Pair` class, for example JavaFX, TestNG have some.

And all of these should be wrapped in array or `List`, something like:

```
List<MyTuple> tuples = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on usage. Assuming the type is int [] (array of size 2):

-If you just want to store, use one of the List implementations (your choice will basically be between LinkedList and Vector depending on the insertion pattern)

-If you need to iterate in an orderly fasion, a custom TreeSet would work:

```
TreeSet<int []> set = new TreeSet<int[]>(new Comparator<int []>()
{
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {return o1[0] != o2[0] ? o1[0]-o2[0] : o1[1]-o2[1];}
});
```

-If there are many lookups, use a HashSet

Comment: You should never use a `Vector` unless you need a synchronized collection. Your choice would be between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`

Comment: @MikkelLøkke "never" is a strong word, especially when you don't know all the details of how the data is used. See it as "peace of mind vs. winning a few microseconds" in 99% of cases.

Comment: It may be a strong word, but it's also accurate. A `Vector` is essentially a synchronized `ArrayList`. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Peace of Mind" surely you already know whether your class has a critical section or not? And if it does, you would probably still be better off using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke That's just the thing, we don't know what the OP will do with his data! But otherwise, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Lang, has an `ImmutablePair`, that you can put in a `Set` if you want. Whether `Set` is useful in this case, depends on what you want to do with the data. Sets are Iterable, but cannot be read (can only be checked for), also worth mentioning is that by default, in a Set <100, 13> and <100, 14> are not the same item (ie, if you add both, you will have 2 items with "key" 100). Furthermore, if you care about ordering, I would probably use a TreeSet/TreeMap instead.